# PyQt5 heading and subheading

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to recreate this [image] in PyQt5.
The problem is the space between the 2 labels (the heading and the subheading).

This is my current code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class NoResultsWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # "No results found" -> heading
        self.noResultsLabel = QLabel("No results found", self)
        self.noResultsLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.noResultsLabel.setStyleSheet("font-size: 24px;")

        # "Try different keywords or remove search filters" -> subheading
        self.instructionLabel = QLabel(
            "Try different keywords or remove search filters", self
        )
        self.instructionLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.instructionLabel.setStyleSheet("font-size: 14px; color: gray;")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.noResultsLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.instructionLabel)
        layout.setSpacing(10)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("No Results")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 200)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = NoResultsWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

that outputs this:
[image]

Does anyone know how can I get rid of the space between the two labels? Or have in mind an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: QLabel, like other text widgets in Qt, supports a [basic HTML subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), why don't you use a *single* label with different `<font>` tags for each line, separated by a simple `<br>`?

Comment: Add the line `layout.addStretch(1)` after the line `layout.setSpacing(10)`

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the label.setGeometry function to put it where you want. I don't know if it also works in Python, so let me know if it works.

In C++ (maybe Python) we do:

```
YourLabel.setGeometry(posX,posY,height,width)
```

Comment: No, setting hardcoded geometries is almost *never* a good solution (especially when using text based widgets), and also completely useless if those widgets are part of a layout.